# How to overload operator in base-derived classes?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

As shown in https://godbolt.org/z/WhEqjaehc

Code is like

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class BaseFile {
protected:
    std::ofstream file;

public:
    template<typename T>
    BaseFile &operator<<(const T &v) {
        file << v;
        return *this;
    }
    BaseFile &operator<<(std::ostream &(*pf)(std::ostream &) ) {
        file << pf;
        return *this;
    }
};

class TmpFile : public BaseFile {
public:
    template<typename T>
    TmpFile &operator<<(const T &v) {
        //some additional operation into file
        file << v << "some suffix maybe";
        return *this;
    }
    TmpFile &operator<<(std::ostream &(*pf)(std::ostream &) ) {
        file << pf;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(){
    TmpFile f("path");
    f << "123" << std::endl;
}
```

`BaseFile` is a base class and `TmpFile` is derived from it.
If I want to change `std::ofstream file` in `BaseFile` into `private`, then how to implement operator<< in TmpFile without directly using `file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call base class method explicitly:

```
    template<typename T>
    TmpFile &operator<<(const T &v) {
        //some additional operation into file
        // file << v << "some suffix maybe";
        BaseFile::operator<<(v);
        BaseFile::operator<<("some suffix maybe");
        return *this;
    }
    TmpFile &operator<<(std::ostream &(*pf)(std::ostream &) ) {
        BaseFile::operator<<(pf);
        return *this;
    }
```

[Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rjoYTa7er).

It is also possible to chain the calls:

```
BaseFile::operator<<(v).BaseFile::operator<<("some suffix maybe");
BaseFile::operator<<(v) << "some suffix maybe";
```

but for me it's less readable.